# Make this seats busy

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my `DATABASE`. First table is table of `seats` that consists of `row`, `seat` and `availability`. Second table is table of `tickets` that consists of `purchased seats`.

```
 - CREATE TABLE Seats(
Seat INT,
Row INT,
Availability BIT)
 - INSERT INTO Seats VALUES (1,1,1), (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (2,2,1)
 - CREATE TABLE Purchased(
Seat INT,
Row INT)
- INSERT INTO Purchased VALUES (1,1), (2,2)
```

I want to change `availability` to `0` for `seat` that are in `Purchased` table without repeating `UPDATE ... SET...WHERE` several times.

The result need to be
`- SEATS = (1,1,0), (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (2,2,0)`

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. SQL Server is not MySQL, and it's highly unlikely you're using them both simultaneously. Please [edit] your post to remove the tag that does not apply. Tag spamming is a very quick way to collect downvotes and get your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update and Join together for this.

For MySql;

```
update Seats s
inner join Purchased p on s.Seat = p.Seat and s.Row = p.Row
set s.Availability = 0;
```

For SQL Server;

```
update s
set s.Availability = 0
from Seats s
inner join Purchased p on s.Seat = p.Seat and s.Row = p.Row
```